# onload button in javascript

Tags: javascript, jbutton, onload

Via the link: http://boukestar.nl/ani-map/ you can see that I've set up a vector svg map that is animated.

My only problem is that I dont no how to deactivate or onload a button / country when you click on a other button / country. All the buttons stay active when you click on a other button.

That results in not correct information from a country that's loaded.

**HTML**

```
<button class="usa" onClick="usa()" class="hidden">Verendigde Staten</button><div id="landusa" class="hide"><img src="svg/infovs.svg" viewBox="0 0 1087 841.89"></div><div id="div1" style="display: none;"></div>
```

**JS**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    var svg,
        button;
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function init() {
        button = document.querySelector('.usa');
        svg = document.querySelector('svg');
        button.addEventListener('click', clickHandler, false);
    });

    function clickHandler(e) {
        svg.classList.toggle('usa');
        e.target.classList.toggle('on');
    }
}());
```

Has anybody an idea?
Many thanks!
Bouke

Comment: You could on click remove the class 'usa' from all SVGs and then add the class to the desired SVG.

Comment: Something like [this](http://jsbin.com/gosose/edit?js,output)?

Comment: That will deactivate the country in the map when you click on one of the buttons...Is it not possible to place an onload action as a new function?

Comment: @Mihailo, that comes close! http://boukestar.nl/ani-map/ When you activate by clicking the button Verenigde Staten and then you click on Brazilie you will see that the info of the country and the land (us) Verenigde Staten will be closed / switch. Really nice. But not yet the buttom self. This on stays active after switching.

Comment: Did you manage to fix it? If you're still at the stadium the link leads to. You're close you just need to do the same with the `on` class that the buttons get + probably some other class removals.

Comment: I'm a step further. You can see that the buttons are independent from each other: http://boukestar.nl/ani-map/test.html But now  the countries stay enabled when you click on a other button. But just one country must be selected per button click. Any idea? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution. If you put your code in a JSFiddle or CodePen then I can test it:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function init(){
    var svg = document.querySelector("svg"),
        currentCountry,
        currentButton;


    function toggle(clickedButtonCountry){
        var clickedButton = document.querySelector("." + clickedButtonCountry);
        currentButton.classList.remove("on");
        clickedButton.classList.add("on");
        clickedButton.classList.remove("hidden");
        currentButton.classList.add("hidden");
        svg.classList.remove(currentCountry);
        svg.classList.add(clickedButtonCountry);
        currentCountry = clickedButtonCountry;
        currentButton = clickedButton;
    }
});
</script>

<button class="usa hidden" onClick="toggle('usa')">Verendigde Staten</button>
<button class="brazil hidden" onClick="toggle('brazil')">Brazil</button>

<svg></svg>
```

---

This way Javascript "remembers" which country is currently displayed, and then when someone clicks on a button it "remembers" that country instead.

Some things to keep in mind:

- `usa()` means you have `function usa(){}` somewhere, which you don't (and shouldn't). I think you were going for something like `toggle('usa')`
- You can have multiple classes in one `class` attribute, like `<div class="foo1 bar2"></div>`
- `document.querySelector` only returns *one* element. `document.querySelectorAll` returns many.
- Using `classList.toggle` can get a little weird because it's not specific about whether the class should be added or removed. I prefer to explicitly use `classList.add` and `classList.remove`. `classList.contains` is very useful.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't make the buttons independed from each other. Clicking on the Usa button and then on the Brazil button let them both stay active instead of just the latest selected button. Here you can test it with my files: https://jsfiddle.net/MrStar80/8bL96k6g/

Comment: I guess Im really close now, but the countries are not independent yet: boukestar.nl/ani-map/test.html As you can see the buttons are working fine.
Have updated my scripts on: https://jsfiddle.net/MrStar80/8bL96k6g/7/ can you have a look and test it? thanks!